# How to prevent make from communicating any variable to a submake?

Tags: shell, makefile

I am unable to prevent `make` from communicating any variables to a submake.  I've read the manual and I've followed their advice (resetting `MAKEOVERRIDES` and `MAKEFLAGS`) but it's still not working has I think it should.

Consider the following prototype Makefile:

```
${warning $(MAKEOVERRIDES)}
${warning $(MAKEFLAGS)}
${warning $(VAR)}

none:
    $(MAKE) -f Makefile MAKEOVERRIDES= MAKEFLAGS= all

all:
    echo done!
```

If I `make VAR=10 none`, I get the following:

```
Makefile:2: VAR=10
Makefile:3: 
Makefile:4: 10
make -f Makefile MAKEOVERRIDES= MAKEFLAGS= all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/adriano/sandbox/makes'
Makefile:2: 
Makefile:3: 
Makefile:4: 10
echo done!
done!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/adriano/sandbox/makes'
```

Meaning that `make` is communication `VAR` to the submake. Is this the correct behaviour?

I've tried `unexport VAR` and `bash -c make ...` without any luck.

EDIT: I've modified `none`'s recipe to: `bash -c "echo $$MAKEOVERRIDES $$MAKEFLAGS $$VAR" ; make ...`

This way I found out that VAR is actually being passed through the environment that make creates for the commands to be executed and not through the other variables (the other variables are also passed this way to make).

I think my question now is: how can I create a fresh shell/environment to run my sub make?

EDIT: Someone asked why am I trying to this; I'll try to answer to that here.

I have a "module" which uses a variable named CONFIG.  In order to build this module I need to build another partially unrelated "module" which also uses CONFIG, but with a different value.  The problem is that when I try to build the "sub-module" CONFIG contains the value of the "super-module."  I could specify CONFIG when making the "sub-module" however both modules use many variables with the same name and trying to specify them all would make the modules tightly coupled which is something I cannot afford.

How can this be so difficult...

Comment: Do you want the first Make to refrain from exporting the variable, or the second Make to refuse to accept it?

Comment: I want the first make to not export anything. In other words I want the second make to start fresh, as if called from say a shell.

Comment: You can omit *one* variable like this: `$(MAKE) -f Makefile VAR= all`, but I don't know how to omit *all* variables from the command line.

Answer (score 6):

This is wrong:

```
none:
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile MAKEOVERRIDES= MAKEFLAGS= all
```

These variables (`MAKEOVERRIDES` and `MAKEFLAGS`) are set in the *environment* by the parent make to be passed down to the sub-makes.  Setting overrides on these values inside the recipe won't help, because make has to set the environment for the recipe before it actually starts the commands in the recipe (of course).

You have to override/remove these values *in the parent makefile*, so that those changes are seen by the parent make before it constructs the sub-make's environment:

```
MAKEOVERRIDES =
none:
        $(MAKE) -f Makefile all
```

There's no perfect way to do this.  However, you can play a trick that will work most of the time:

```
unexport $(shell echo '$(MAKEOVERRIDES)' | sed 's/=[^ ]*//g')
MAKEOVERRIDES =
```

The first line tries to unexport all the variables in `MAKEOVERRIDES` and the second line resets MAKEOVERRIDES.  There are a few issues with this.  One is that if MAKEOVERRIDES is empty, it will use "unexport" by itself which unexports everything.  That can be easily worked around by sticking some bogus variable before the shell function.  The other is that if any variable's value contains whitespace, the expansion will consider it a variable to be unexported.  That's probably OK, but it's odd.

I can't think of any better way to do it.

You don't really say *why* you want to do this.  Have you considered doing something different, such as running the commands where you want to have a "vanilla" environment using `env`; for example if you want to run a command with a limited and specific set of env vars, you can run:

```
test:
        env -i PATH='$(PATH)' LANG='$(LANG)' runMyCommand --with --my arguments
```

Unfortunately some versions of `env` use `-` instead of `-i`; check your man page.

Alternatively, you can try to start a login shell which will re-read the user's shell setup environment from scratch:

```
test:
        /bin/sh -lc 'runMyCommand --with --my arguments'
```

EDIT: It's difficult because what you're asking to do (restrict the environment of the sub-make) is tricky.

Luckily based on your description, it doesn't seem necessary.  Make has a hierarchy of importance for finding variable values.  The command line is the highest level (well, there's `override` but we'll ignore that).  After that comes variables set in the makefile itself.  And last and lowest comes variables imported from the environment (well, default variables are even lower but we'll ignore that too).

So if your goal is to allow the variables in the sub-makes to not be affected by command line variables given to the upper-level makes, then all this rigmarole of getting the variables out of the environment is not necessary.  Variables set in the sub-makefiles will take precedence over the values in the environment.  So all you have to do is get rid of the variables set on the command line, which I've already shown how to do above, by setting MAKEOVERRIDES.

Comment: I've tried out your solution. Still doesn't work. Same result as above.

Comment: Yes... the problem is this from the GNU make manual http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html: _Except by explicit request, make exports a variable only if it is either defined in the environment initially or set on the command line_.  So just unsetting MAKEOVERRIDES is not enough to remove it from the environment of sub-makes.

Comment: Can you take a look at my last EDIT. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know if it is suitable in your case, but I've found quite elegant way not to pass parameters from CLI to sub-make via MAKEFLAGS, but only via env, making them not to override variables defined in the sub make:

Makefile:

```makefile
override MAKEFLAGS=$(MFLAGS) --

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    @echo PARAM_1=$(PARAM_1)
    @echo PARAM_2=$(PARAM_2)
    $(MAKE) -f child.mk PARAM_3=parent_cli
```

child.mk:

```makefile
PARAM_1:=child

.PHONY: all
all:
    @echo MAKEFLAGS=$(MAKEFLAGS)
    @echo PARAM_1=$(PARAM_1)
    @echo PARAM_2=$(PARAM_2)
    @echo PARAM_3=$(PARAM_3)
```

Execution:

```
$ make --no-print-directory -j3 PARAM_1=cli PARAM_2=cli
MAKEFLAGS=-j3 --jobserver-auth=3,4 --no-print-directory --
PARAM_1=cli
PARAM_2=cli
make -f child.mk PARAM_3=parent_cli
MAKEFLAGS= -j3 --jobserver-auth=3,4 --no-print-directory -- PARAM_3=parent_cli
PARAM_1=child
PARAM_2=cli
PARAM_3=parent_cli
```

Execution with commented-out override:

```
MAKEFLAGS= -j3 --jobserver-auth=3,4 --no-print-directory -- PARAM_2=cli PARAM_1=cli
PARAM_1=cli
PARAM_2=cli
make -f child.mk PARAM_3=parent_cli
MAKEFLAGS= -j3 --jobserver-auth=3,4 --no-print-directory -- PARAM_3=parent_cli PARAM_1=cli PARAM_2=cli
PARAM_1=cli
PARAM_2=cli
PARAM_3=parent_cli
```

This way all the make-specific options like -j are still passed to sub-make, but options that are intended only to parent makefile won't cause conflict with child makefile. That could be useful if child makefile is some 3-rd party makefile you do not control.