# "Unsupported architecture" when building iOS app and running Mac makefile

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, makefile, clang

As an Xcode build phase for building an iOS app, I am using a `makefile` in order to build a load of other stuff as a dependency (easier than setting up lots of complex Xcode build rules I find).

One of the steps in the `makefile` now includes building a Mac command line app that is needed to proces and package up some assets for the app.

Unfortunately, when `make` is run from within Xcode, some environment variables seem to get passed to it, so that when it tries to compile the Mac app from an external `makefile`, it seems to think that the architecture should be iPhone instead of Mac.

My `makefile` is very simple:

```
APP_NAME = myAppName
SOURCE = main.m

$(APP_NAME): $(SOURCE)
    cc -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa -o $(APP_NAME) $(SOURCE)
```

**So, the question:**

How can I force clang to use the native architecture instead of the one that seems to be in the environment?

*Edit*: Or: Have `make` not take on the environment that seems to be passed from Xcode?

**What I'm seeing:**

When building the iOS app I get a load of errors saying "Unsupported architecture" for really low level headers (e.g. first is cdefs.h). When I look more closely, it becomes clear that it's when building the Mac tool's main.m. It builds absolutely fine when running `make` as usual on the command line - it seems it's only when building through Xcode that I get this problem.

Comment: If you determine what the environment variables are that are bad, you can just reset those variables in make.  To see the complete list of environment variables you can (from a rule in the makefile perhaps) run something like `env | sort`.  Then suppose you notice an env.var. `MAKE_ME_AN_IPHONE=true` you can in your makefile add `MAKE_ME_AN_IPHONE =` or, if you have a sufficiently-new version of GNU make, `unexport MAKE_ME_AN_IPHONE` to get rid of that value.

Comment: Thanks! My solution turned out to be similar, but not quite the same...

Answer (score 0):

In order to run `make` within a "vanilla" environment, I used the following trick when calling it:

```
env -i PATH='$(PATH)' LANG='$(LANG)' make
```

...as described within this anwer: [How to prevent make from communicating any variable to a submake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050611/how-to-prevent-make-from-communicating-any-variable-to-a-submake)

From `env`'s man page: "The option '-i' causes env to completely ignore the environment it inherits."